# CollectionView scrolling horizontally constraints issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView that scrolls horizontally while all other tableView cells only scrolls vertically. I added the constraints in storyboard to resize and fit all size screens. When I run the project on the iPhone X simulator it looks perfect. But once I try another size like 7 plus it causes the collection view cell to get smaller and shows next cell. However, the tableview cells keep their correct size. How can I prevent this?

[image: Here is a photo of both simulators]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` method of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

and return correct size for your cell, for example:

```
return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
```

Example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    @IBOutlet private weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.delegate = self
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I doing it correctly? because I am now getting some errors                          


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, transitionLayoutForOldLayout fromLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, newLayout toLayout: UICollectionViewLayout) -> UICollectionViewTransitionLayout {
        collectionView(UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath)
        
        return  CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
    }

Comment: added example to answer